# let $f$ be a convex function, homogeneous of degree 1, prove that $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}, f(x + y) \leq f(x) + f(y) $

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

We are given a function ${f \colon   \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\}$. $ f $ is a convex function and homogeneous of degree $1$  . So for every  $t  \geq 0 $, $ f(tx)= tf(x)$. Now we want to prove that : $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}, f(x + y) \leq f(x) + f(y)  $

I have tried using the property of convex functions that says : $ \forall t \in [0,1]\hspace{0.5cm}    \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}, \hspace{0.5cm} f(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) $

It's close to what i am trying to prove but i don't know how to end the demonstration at this point. Please give me a hint on how to get rid of the $t$ on both sides of the inequality or maybe a different method of demonstration. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put $t=\frac 1 2 $ and use homogenity.

Comment: Thank you for your help.